# Could anyone explain me this makefile?

Tags: makefile

this is the makefile :

```
TOP=../..                 
DIRNAME=base_class/string           

H = regexp.h regmagic.h string_version.h          
CSRCS = regerror.c regsub.c EST_strcasecmp.c
TSRCS = 
CPPSRCS = EST_String.cc EST_Regex.cc EST_Chunk.cc regexp.cc

LOCAL_DEFAULT_LIBRARY = eststring

SRCS = $(CPPSRCS) $(CSRCS)
OBJS = $(CPPSRCS:.cc=.o) $(CSRCS:.c=.o)

FILES = $(SRCS) $(TSRCS) $(H) Makefile
LOCAL_INCLUDES=-I.

ALL = .buildlibs

include $(TOP)/config/common_make_rules
```

now i know these part is variable

```
TOP=../..                 
DIRNAME=base_class/string           

H = regexp.h regmagic.h string_version.h          
CSRCS = regerror.c regsub.c EST_strcasecmp.c
TSRCS = 
CPPSRCS = EST_String.cc EST_Regex.cc EST_Chunk.cc regexp.cc

LOCAL_DEFAULT_LIBRARY = eststring

SRCS = $(CPPSRCS) $(CSRCS)
```

what i do not know is :

```
OBJS = $(CPPSRCS:.cc=.o) $(CSRCS:.c=.o)
```

pls tell me the meaning of above statement , it is best if you figure out what above statement omit.  thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look this up in the GNU make manual.  The above is equivalent to writing `$(CPPSRCS:%.cc=%.o)` (and ditto for `CSRCS`).  In both of these, it goes through each word in the variable and if it matches the left-hand side of the equality, it's replaced with the right-hand side.  So if a word matches the pattern `%.cc` (where `%` to make matches any sequence of characters), then it's replaced with `%.o` (where `%` is the same as in the original).  The form you see is a special case where you can omit the `%` if it's the first thing in both sides.

So, given `CPPSRCS = EST_String.cc EST_Regex.cc EST_Chunk.cc regexp.cc`, then `$(CPPSRCS:.cc=.o)` expands to `EST_String.o EST_Regex.o EST_Chunk.o regexp.o`.